# Metric functions in Haskell Cartesian.Types

Tags: haskell

I'm having problems using the Cartesian.Types library. Some of the functions appear available for me, others don't

```
Prelude Cartesian.Types> let a1 = V1 1.0
Prelude Cartesian.Types> show a1
"V1 1.0"
Prelude Cartesian.Types> fmap (*2) a1
V1 2.0
```

But..

```
Prelude Cartesian.Types> norm a1

<interactive>:46:1: Not in scope: ‘norm’
```

What am I missing?

Steve

Comment: Which library is this? I can’t find any library with a `Cartesian.Types` module on [Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/).

Comment: There is no `norm` in [Cartesian.Types](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Cartesian-0.6.0.0/docs/Cartesian-Types.html) Generally a module named `Types` is expected to export types, not functions.

Comment: Thanks for finding the package @n.'pronouns'm.! Furthermore it would appear that that package doesn’t have a `norm` function at all, which would explain why OP is getting an error about it being ‘not in scope’.

Comment: I think `norm` is provided by [Linear.Metric](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear-1.20.5/docs/Linear-Metric.html#t:Metric). Your type may be an instance of `Metric` but it doesn't mean you can use the methods, you need to import the class definition for that.

Comment: The `Cartesian` package seems to be intended to just provide some extra functions to the types from the [`linear`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear) package, so yeah – using `Linear.Metric.norm` would be the obvious choice, or equivalently [`Data.VectorSpace.magnitude`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.16/docs/Data-VectorSpace.html#v:magnitude) (which is better typed, but requires orphan instances from [`Data.VectorSpace.Free`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-vector-spaces-0.1.5.0/docs/Data-VectorSpace-Free.html)).